# Pourquoi « Nom de Dieu » est-il une injure ?

Tags: expressions, jurons, religion

Pourquoi "Nom de Dieu" est-il une injure ? Est-ce une exclusivité de la langue française ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

« Nom de Dieu » n'est pas vraiment une [injure](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injure), au sens où cela ne s'adresse pas à une personne en particulier. C'est une interjection et plus précisément un [juron](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juron), qui en l'occurrence a un caractère blasphématoire (pour les religions monothéistes, on ne doit pas « invoquer en vain le nom du Seigneur », c'est l'un des dix commandements). Le blasphème en lui-même a bien sûr perdu de son côté provocateur dans beaucoup de sociétés, mais il servait à signifier l'intensité de la réaction de l'auteur, que ce soit de la surprise, de la colère…

Comment: Source : Exode 20:7, Tu n'invoqueras point le nom de l'Éternel, ton Dieu, en vain ; car l'Éternel ne laissera point impuni celui qui invoque son nom en vain. (Traduction Louis Segond)

Answer (score 6):

En anglais il y "By God!", en allemand "Gott verdammt", en flamand aussi, etc..

Le Catholicisme qui était très présent en France interdisait de prononcer le nom de Dieu sans respect (d'après les dix commandements judaïques).

De plus, il est interdit (dans la religion chrétienne) de prendre Dieu à témoin : donc "Par Dieu" (pardi!) et "Nom de Dieu" ("abrégé" dans une certaine BD en ROgnnnntuuddjuuuu, ailleurs en sacrebleu, morbleu, etc...) sont donc des blasphèmes qu'on ne prononcait pas en bonne société.

Comment: en anglais ce serait pas plutot "for God's sake!" ?

Comment: Oui mais ce n'est pas un blasphème....

Comment: En anglais ce serait plutôt "By God's name" que je n'ai jamais entendu. Par contre on pourrait se demander si "By Jove" n'en serait pas une atténuation, Jove étant utilisé pour Jupiter lui-même pour Dieu.

Comment: "Le Catholicisme très présent en France" il était, mais plus maintenant. (Aujourd'hui moins de 5 personnes sur 100 vont à la messe). J'ai updaté ta réponse.

Answer (score 1):

L'explication de cette expression vient du paganisme : quand la religion chrétienne s'est imposée, il est devenu interdit d'invoquer les anciens dieux (Mercure, Junon, Zeus, etc). « Nom de Dieu » a remplacé *« par Apollon »* ou *« par Cernunnos »*. On dit « nom de Dieu » parce que justement on ne peut plus dire le nom du dieu.